# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.C

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, migration

This is my connection string key/value pair:

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database={databaseName};Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

I have tried other options but still no clue what is happening. I am implementing IDesignTimeDbContextFactory, I have one parametless constructor as well and I inherit from IdentityDbContext.
This is what is written in the package manager console:

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
>   
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)

Comment: Does your connection string really contain `{databaseName}`? Do you plan to actually replace that with a real database name without curly braces? Can you show the code that tries to use this connection string?

Comment: No, it contains the name which after the update I want the database to be created with. I added the initial migration but now I struggle with the update: "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=Cardstone;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }

Comment: Error is after the connection.A mapping exists between DbConnection object in c# and the SQL Server Database.Your code tried to perform an UPDATE of the database and failed.This type failure means one of two things 1) The definition of the Server column is different from the data.The database is defined as a varchar and you send an integer. 2)Updating a table in database that has a primary key.Update only works if the key already exists in table. Key doesn't exist then you have to use Insert instead of Update.Will get an error if you Insert a key that already exists.If key exists use Update.

Comment: This is how it is fixed:

    services.AddDbContext<{nameOfContext}>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("{nameOfKeyOfConnectionString}"));
            });
I am not sure why, but that why by method call the connection string is found!